# What's the reading order for Age of X?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I've seen several discussions regarding the preferred reading order for the "[Age of X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_X)" storyline but it seems they just listed the release order and quite often in these large events, that's not the way it works.

As the title says, what's the reading order (and why)?

Comment: “it seems they just listed the release order and quite often, that's not the way it works” — really? They should release them in a different order then.

Comment: It's *very* uncommon that the release order is *not* the preferred reading order. The AvX storyline is the only one I can think of that isn't, and that was only because of some mixed up publish/release dates.

Comment: @phantom42 - In this instance, there were 11 comics in this event, published over a period of 3 months in four different lines. The publishing order is slightly helpful (e.g. don't read the ones from March before the ones from April), but it's not useful in telling you which of the three published in April to read first.

Answer (score 1):

Handily, each issue of the Age of X comics lists the *suggested* next issue in the bottom corner of the final page, something that **all large crossover comic events like this should do** (but invariably don't).

- [Age of X (Alpha)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_X:_Alpha_Vol_1_1)
- [X-Men Legacy #245](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_245)
- [New Mutants #22](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_Mutants_Vol_1_22)
- [X-Men Legacy #246](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_246)
- [New Mutants #23](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_Mutants_Vol_1_23)
- [Age of X: Universe #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_X:_Universe_Vol_1_1)
- [X-Men Legacy #247](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_247)
- [New Mutants #24](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_Mutants_Vol_1_24)
- [Age of X: Universe #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_X:_Universe_Vol_1_2)
- [X-Men Legacy (Aftermath 1/2) #248](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_248)
- [X-Men Legacy (Aftermath 2/2) #249](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Legacy_Vol_1_249)

All of these issues were collected in a [single hardback edition](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/41375/x-men_age_of_x_hc_hardcover) which also contained the "*[historical logs](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_X:_Historical_Log_Vol_1)*" that were QR coded to various issues and available as DLC.

There was also a helpful checklist in New Mutants #23. Note that it excludes the two 'aftermath' comics

[image]